# Nested JSON Feed Returns Error

Tags: json, swift, nested

I'm new to JSON feeds and swift 4 in general. I'm having trouble printing data from a nested JSON feed. First off, I'm unsure if I'm calling the array properly in my do statement. Second, when I build the app, I get the following long error. Could anyone help me decipher this? My code is at the bottom of the post. Thank you in advance.

> 2017-12-06 12:58:48.604154-0500 PlayerRankDOTA2[91584:6694163] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
>   Error jsonErr dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [PlayerRankDOTA2.PlayerStatsParent.(CodingKeys in _053A446F694D6B16CE13A0E302B3B14A).rankings, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), PlayerRankDOTA2.PlayerStats.(CodingKeys in _053A446F694D6B16CE13A0E302B3B14A).score], debugDescription: "Parsed JSON number <3099.96838722024> does not fit in Int.", underlyingError: nil))"

```
import UIKit

struct PlayerStatsParent:Decodable{
    let rankings: [PlayerStats]
}

struct PlayerStats:Decodable {
    let personaname: String
    let score: Int
    let solo_competitive_rank: Int
    let avatar: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.opendota.com/api/rankings"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error)  in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            //print(dataAsString)
            do{
                let playerStatsParent = try JSONDecoder().decode(PlayerStatsParent.self, from: data)
                print(playerStatsParent.rankings)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error jsonErr", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.opendota.com/api/rankings"

}
```

Comment: Please include the JSON response you are trying to decode.

Comment: I’m trying to record every variable from the PlayerStats structure, but those are stored inside of the rankings variable of the PlayerStatsParent structure

Comment: I meant the actual JSON that you receive from the API... Without seeing what you are trying to decode, it's hard to tell what't wrong.

Comment: my apologies, the feed is very long, but can be found at https://api.opendota.com/api/rankings. For example, one integer has the following information {"hero_id":null,"rankings":[{"account_id":125661623,"score":3099.96838722024,"personaname":"HigleHateYou","name":null,"avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cb/cb130c0899b1e4c8a6959bb5fbbc1f0a654cf580.jpg","last_login":null,"solo_competitive_rank":5498}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make several changes to your `PlayerStats`. First of all, `score` has to be `Double`, since that's the format the API is returning. Secondly, all values can be `null` in the JSON response. One way to tackle this issue is to define all properties as optionals.

```
struct PlayerStats:Decodable {
    let personaname: String?
    let score: Double?
    let solo_competitive_rank: Int?
    let avatar: String?
}
```

After changing your `PlayerStats` struct to the above format, the decoding works just fine.

Comment: This worked perfectly! If you don't mind me asking, how did you discover that the score variable was returning from the API as Double?

Comment: I checked the actual JSON response both from my browser and then from Postman.